# Is it possible to force compiler to use the name of "working" directory to construct all full names from includes?

Tags: c++, path, include, environment-variables

Let us assume that in `first.h` we have `#include "aaa/second.h"` and in the `aaa/second.h` we have `#include "bbb/third.h"`. I think that in the "default settings" the compiler will complain if "third.h" is not located in "aaa/bbb".

Is it possible to change this behavior in such a way that the directory, in which the `first.cpp` is located is used to construct the full names in all includes?

For example, if "first.h" is located in '/home/bucky/' then `#include "bbb/third.h"` (from "aaa/second.h") should be interpreted as `/home/bucky/bbb/third.h` and not as `/home/bucky/aaa/bbb/third.h`.

**EDITS**

I cannot change the whole source code. In the code quotation marks are used instead of angle brackets.

I compile using `g++ -std=c++0x name.cpp -o name` in the command line. I do it in two different terminals. It looks like in the first terminal the working directory is used to construct the full names and in the second terminal it is not the case. I am almost sure that it happens because of the environment variables but I do not know which ones. So, my question is, to larger extent, what environment variables can force the compiler to construct full names using the working directory.

**EDIT 2**

In my test.cpp file I include "first.h". This inclusion does not cause any problem (complier sees "first.h"). The "first.h" file includes "ppp/second.h". It also causes no problems. But "ppp/second.h" includes "ppp/third.h" and this is the place where the problem appears. I think that the reason of the problem is that "second.h" tries to find "third.h" in the "ppp" subdirectory of the directory where second.h is located. In other words, second.h tries to find the third.h in the "ppp/ppp" subdirectory (because second.h is located in the ppp subdirectory).

In another terminal, the same compilation command, in the same directory does not cause any problem. The reason, is obviously in the values of the environment varibales.

Comment: You're missing either quotation marks or angle brackets in your second `#include`.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, thank you. I needed quotation marks there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The exact mechanics depend on the compiler but the short and the long of it is that you need to configure your compiler to include the project path in the search path. For GCC and clang that’s done via the `-I` command line flag (`-I path/of/first.cpp`). This configuration would usually be done in the project settings (if you’re working with an IDE), a Makefile or similar.

Since you’re talking about environment variables: the flags that are passed to the `g++` and `c++` compiler are controlled by the `CXXFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` variables.

Comment: I thought that quotes should be used for your own headers `aaa/second.h` that is found in `/home/bucky/aaa/second.h` with `-I/home/bucky` to direct the compiler where to look. Angle brackets are used only for sytem headers `time.h` that is in `/usr/include/time.h`. In reality, most compilers don't distinguish between <> and ""

Comment: @Dan No, compilers *do* distinguish between them. The difference is what Kerrek wrote but you can (and in my book, *should*) use angle brackets whenever you’re not using includes relative to the local directory. That’s what’s happening here: you are using includes relative to the (configured) search path. Angle brackets are right and proper here. They are definitely *not* restricted to system headers.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, I made two edits to my initial questions to clarify what exactly my problem is. To be short, I think the behavior of the compiler can be changed without use of -I option and without replacing "" by "<>".

Comment: @Roman See the previous comment and Kerrek’s answer – you don’t need to change `"…"` to `<…>`. Why do you think that this can be achieved without `-I`? Why do you want to do this? You seem to want to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @DanS Ah, I take that back. §16.2/7 advises (but doesn’t mandate) that `<…>` be used for “headers provided with the implementation” and `"…"` for “sources outside the control of the implementation”.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, my problem is that two terminals behave differently because of values of environment variables. My interpretation is that in one terminal the name of the working directory is always used to construct the full names and in the other one it is not the case. I really need to find out what environment variable causes this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You should set up include paths for your project globally. In your example, you would pass some option like `-I /home/bucky` to your compiler (if it is GCC or Clang). MSVC has analogous options.

(All #includes are searched relative to the include paths. The difference between `<...>` and `"..."` is that the latter also searches the current directory.)

Comment: in my code I have only `"..."`. I use `g++` to compile. I did not use the `-I` option. In one terminal the compiler seems to use the name of the working directory to construct all full names and in another terminal it is not the case. It happens because of environment variables but I do not know which ones.

Comment: I made two edits to my initial questions to clarify what exactly my problem is. To be short, I think the behavior of the compiler can be changed without use of -I option and without replacing "" by "<>".